# NodeJS Won't Import a Non-NodeJS File

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, commonjs

I have the following two files on my site:

- `firebase.js`
- `gridsome-server.js`

The firebase.js is a 'regular' javascript file with the following contents:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
  apiKey: '[APIKEY],
  authDomain: '[AUTHDOMAIN],
  databaseURL: '[DATABASEURL],
  projectId: '[PROJECTID],
  storageBucket: '[STORAGEBUCKET],
  messagingSenderId: '[MESSAGINGSENDERID],
  appId: '[APPID]'
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

const db = firebase.firestore()

export default db
```

Now, I want to import the default export (`db`) into `gridsome-server.js` - which (I believe) is a nodejs file.  Now, I thought I could do the following:  `const db = require('./src/config/firebase.js')` - but that did not work.  I got the following error message:

```
Initializing plugins...
SyntaxError: gridsome.server.js: Unexpected identifier (1:12)

> 1 | const db = require('./src/config/firebase')
    |            ^
  2 |
  3 | module.exports = function(api) {
  4 |   api.loadSource(({ addCollection }) => {
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

So I changed `require` to `import` - as follows:  `import db from './src/config/firebase`.  But that also gave me an error:

```
Initializing plugins...
C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\gridsome.server.js:2
import db from './src/config/firebase'
       ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Plugins.initialize (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\Plugins.js:45:11)
    at App.init (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\App.js:120:18)
    at App.bootstrap (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\App.js:49:16)
    at module.exports (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\index.js:12:18)
    at module.exports (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\develop.js:20:21)
    at C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\index.js:44:12
    at Command.program.command.description.option.option.action.args (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\index.js:13:44)
    at Command.listener (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

So I am stuck -- how can I import `firebase.js` into `gridsome-server.js`?

**Update**

I also tried changing to a named export in `firebase.js` (i.e., to `export const db`) and using a named import in `gridsome-server.js` (i.e., `import { db } from...`).  That also lead to an error:

```
Initializing plugins...
C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\gridsome.server.js:2
import { db } from './src/config/firebase'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Plugins.initialize (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\Plugins.js:45:11)
    at App.init (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\App.js:120:18)
    at App.bootstrap (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\App.js:49:16)
    at module.exports (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\app\index.js:12:18)
    at module.exports (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\lib\develop.js:20:21)
    at C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\index.js:44:12
    at Command.program.command.description.option.option.action.args (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\gridsome\index.js:13:44)
    at Command.listener (C:\code\tutorials\vue\gridsome\vuetify-gridsome\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Might be using AoT imports, similar to angular.js instead you. you'll need to do `import { db } from ''` The default export might not even work tbh you'll need to export an actual variable `export db` instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Gridsome uses webpack.

Comment: @Andrei  I had also tried `import { db } from ''` and also got an error message.  And I just now changed the `firebase.js` store to `export const db...` and tried `import { db }...` and also got an error :(.

Comment: @Andrei I don't know what an `AoT import` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with how you are importing `FireBase`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

As from the documentation on [NPM website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)

> If you are using native ES6 module with --experimental-modules flag, you should do:
>   `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`

Otherwise you should be importing like this

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
```

Comment: You mean in the `firebase.js` file?  If so, do I also have to a `module.exports`?  And how do I import `firebase/firestore`?  And either way, I thought that node could import regular javascript files using the `require` method.

Comment: Yes,When you import a `regular` js file, it has its own importing and that is handled by `node` and `node` as of today cannot handle imports like `import firebase from 'firebase/app'`

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks.  NOTE -- for anyone who may need it.  I solved it by moving the code from `firebase.js` directly into `gridsome-server.js` and using `commonsjs` syntax.